# remove extra white space in mobile view in html

Tags: html, css

I have a website with slider only on the home page, but when I am viewing it in mobile -> the slider isn't full screen, in image below you can see white spaces and they shouldn't be there.

[image]

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  .page {
    height: 900px !important;
  }
}
```

I've tried to set the height, but nothing is happening. How should I address this problem?

Comment: Surely setting the height to 900px will add the white space, but please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide enough code to replicate your issue - see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: Share your code or create a fiddle.